# Launching Facebook and Twitter application from other iOS app

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios, twitter, uiapplication

Hey guys,
I am still continuing to build my iPhone project and I am having trouble with launching the  facebook application. First of all, I am assuming every SDK Xcode developer knows that the Facebook application doesn't have the facebook or twitter app in the simulation. Since I have a facebook page and a twitter account about my company, I can't seem to test to launch my facebook page from the facebook application or my twitter page from the twitter application because they are not there in the iOS Simulator. So I was wondering how can I open my facebook and twitter page from the facebook and twitter application if they are not there? I don't want to use a Facebook or Twitter URL, then load it into a UIWebView, I want to open the Facebook and Twitter application to launch after the click of a button in my project, then the project will close and open either Facebook or Twitter application (the ones from the app store), so hopefully someone know how they can help me step by step or if they have a code that knows how to run the facebook or twitter application and sorry if my english is not clear enough, but hopefully you can help me or have a better solution to help solve my problem, thanks

Comment: The title is wrong. Want to do this from Xcode? Good luck. And you can also not click on any iOS device so far. It's 'tapping'.

Comment: yea, sorry for my bad english, I'll make it clear, I have a button on one of my views, and when I tap that button, I want that button to launch the facebook application (App Store), and I want it to open my company's facebook page, but I don't know how to open it to my company's facebook page, so maybe you can help me out also, thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the facebook app listens to URI's like `fb://`, so I would suggest googling around for that.

Look here for example: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook

Comment: omg, this exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! now I can practice with these examples!