# URL shemes for apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, url-scheme

I wanted to open Facebook and Twitter apps from my app. I find very simple way like:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

And there are many others url for open different page of Facebook. How can I check if Facebook app exist on iPhone? What happens if the application is not install on device? Now I try to use this method on iOS Simulator but nothing happened. It's bug of iOS Simulator? Only tomorrow I will have chance to check on device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if a URL would likely open ahead of time using the `canOpenURL` method of `UIApplication`.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:

Also! You can pass values for the facebook page you'd like. This Stack Overflow includes a link to a wiki with all the variations:
[Launching Facebook and Twitter application from other iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304811/launching-facebook-and-twitter-application-from-other-ios-app)

Answer (score 3):

If you know the URL scheme that the other app is using (e.g. `fb://` for the Facebook app), you can first ask whether your `UIApplication` object can open such URLs in the first place, with `canOpenURL:`. You can use this, for instance, to decide whether to display a link at all, or whether to direct the user to Safari (with a normal web URL) instead.

As third-party apps cannot be installed on the Simulator as far as I know, the only way to test compatibility with them is on an actual device.